# Get all active Printers

Tags: java, javafx, printing, printers

The Printer-Api delivers an all printers of the system with  `Printer.getAllPrinters()`.

The problem is that the user does not realize that the being selected printer is active.

Are there opportunities only to obtain the active printers?

Could help the `PrinterAttributes`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about javaFX but you can achieve this using Java Print API's [PrintService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/PrintService.html) class.

```
   DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.POSTSCRIPT;
   PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
   aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
   PrintService[] pservices =
             PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, aset);
```

Now you can iterate through these services and use [PrinterState](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/PrinterState.html) and [PrinterStateReason](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/PrinterStateReason.html) Classes to identify whether a print service is still available or not

For Example:

```
       PrinterState prnState = (PrinterState)service.getAttribute(
                                              PrinterState.class);
        if (prnState == PrinterState.STOPPED) {
            PrinterStateReasons prnStateReasons =
                (PrinterStateReasons)service.getAttribute(
                                             PrinterStateReasons.class);
            if ((prnStateReasons != null) &&
                (prnStateReasons.containsKey(PrinterStateReason.SHUTDOWN)))
            {
                throw new PrinterException("PrintService is no longer available.");
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps